# Android: How to use mathematical expression in android

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. And i am making mortgage application. I want to find the monthly interest with following equation.

M= (P *(J/1-(1+J)^-n)) + T

I have received all the values of different fields .But i don't understand how to implement with this equation.

Please suggest me or guide me the way to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Math.pow` method

**sample:**

```
double P;
double J;
double M;
double T;
double n;
M= (P * (J/1- Math.pow((1+J), -n))) + T;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, most of the basic math operators are what you would expect. (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`). The tricky one is exponentiation. Use the `Math` library and the `pow` function, writing something like `Math.pow(a, b)` to compute `a^b`.

For more information, check the Java documentation. For example, `Math.pow` is at: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the Math library Java provides in `Java.lang.Math`

Documentation from google can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math.html)

```
import Java.lang.Math

//a simple exponentiation example

double base = 2.0;
double exponent = 3.0;

double exponentiation_result = Math.pow(base, exponent)
```

Note that the method `Math.pow` requires that you use the `double` class, which stores numbers with decimal-point precision. Other operations, such as division and subtraction, can be done with mathematical symbols

`int y = a * (b - c)`

Your example, left as an exercise, will require use of parentheses to maintain order of operation.